# What initiates primase to add an RNA primer to a DNA strand and what makes it stop?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-genetics

What initiates primase to add an RNA primer to a DNA strand and what makes it stop adding RNA nucleotides? Is there tags added to the DNA back-bone?

Comment: I'm studying "Biology" by Cambell et. al. and nothing is mentioned in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prokaryotic primases are activated by DNA helicase [1, 2] while the eukaryotic ones are triggered when they form a complex with DNA polymerase alpha and its accessory B subunit [2].

I couldn't find too much information about what exactly triggers activation, but according to De Falco M *et al.* (2004):

> [...] synthetic function *(of the prokaryotic primase)* is specifically activated by thymine-containing synthetic bubble structures that mimic early replication intermediates. [3]

It stops when it finishes reading a DNA template:

> The Sso DNA primase utilizes poly-pyrimidine single-stranded DNA templates with low efficiency for de novo synthesis of RNA primers [3].

---

References:

1. Wikipedia contributors, "Primase," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Primase&oldid=593928284 (accessed December 1, 2014).
2. David N. Frick, and Charles C. Richardson. [DNA PRIMASES.](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.biochem.70.1.39) Annual Review of Biochemistry. Vol. 70: 39-80 (Volume publication date July 2001). DOI: 10.1146/annurev.biochem.70.1.39
3. De Falco M, Fusco A, De Felice M, Rossi M, Pisani FM. [The DNA primase of Sulfolobus solfataricus is activated by substrates containing a thymine-rich bubble and has a 3'-terminal nucleotidyl-transferase activity.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15459292) Nucleic Acids Res. 2004 Sep 30;32(17):5223-30. Print 2004.